# How to set up relationship using entity framework core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have Two Model

```csharp
public class User: Entity
{
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And

```csharp
public class CognitoUser : Entity
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public User User{ get; set; }
    public string CognitoName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to set Cognito.UserId as User.Id . I have written the following which is not working can you please correct me as i dont want to create a model CognitoUser into user model.

```csharp
modelBuilder.Entity<CognitoUser>(e =>
{
    e.ToTable("CognitoUser");
    e.HasKey(p => p.UserId);
    e.HasOne(x => x.User)
    .HasForeignKey<User>(c => c.Id);
});
```

Comment: What exactly "is not working" and what does `Entity` look like? And is there also a `Cognito` class as you seem to suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primary keys are required in each Entity which is missing in your `User` Entity.

Using `Fluent API` is optional. If you set your classes right, Entity Framework will understand what you want to achieve.

**Hints:**

- Use `[Key]` attribute to specify a property as primary key
- Prefered primary key format would be `{ClassName}{Id}`
- Use `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` to force database
  to automatically generate primary key for you.
- You can use `Guid` as primary key type, it is always unique and hassle-free

Additionally, check out the code below to see how to create a relation.

```cs
public class User: Entity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CognitoUser: Entity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid CognitoUserId { get; set; }

    public string CognitoName { get; set; }
    
    // relation
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

**Visualization:**

[image]